# Computing area of different pixels classes in a multiple areas raster?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, clip, land-use

I work on forest data. My raster is a binary file : 0 is forest and 1 is non-deforest. I have multiple ROIs in which I would like to know the area of forest (so pixels of value 0 in the ROIs).
I managed to do it with r.report for a single ROI but I have a lot of ROIs and I would like to obtain it for all of them. Here is an example :

[image: ROIs example]

In the example I show, I would like to know area of black pixels in each of the ROIs, and not the sum of them as I obtain with r.report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input the raster and the ROIs into the [Zonal Statistics Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html)

Comment: Thank you it seems to be doing what I need. If i'm right, I just have to multiply the "_sum" column (as I'm working only with 0 and 1) and multiply it by the resolution of my pixels and I would get the area I need ?

Comment: @Zab Exactly. The sum represents the number of pixels contained in the polygon. So multiplying the number of pixels by the known area of a single pixel gives you the total area. If this solution works please consider marking it as an accepted answer by clicking on the check mark on the left side.